# Why does placing a magnet/phone on the left speaker of a Macbook Pro Retina 15" cause the screen to sleep?

Tags: sleep, macbook-pro-retina

I've repeatedly encountered an issue where putting my phone, or headphones, or a magnet (the magnetic power adapter thing) near the speaker port on the left side of a rMBP (or on top of the speaker holes nearby) will cause the display to go to sleep. Is this an intentional design?

Comment: intentional: unlikely; expected: absolutely; A speaker/headphones/magnet all generate a magnetic field.  It sounds that left side of your laptop isn't properly shielded from EMI.

Comment: Whats more likely honestly is that the rMBP has a sensor, which detect a small magnet in the lid, thus putting your screen to sleep.  It sounds like the sensor is so v its actually detecting the magnetic field generated by your phone and headphone.  Apple is notorious weird design decisions in their products, it takes them several iterations, to fix design flaws in their products.

Comment: As @Ramhound said it's likely the sensor in the lid/base thinking it's been closed - just yesterday read about a guy who's metal plate in his arm would put his laptop to sleep accidentally.

Comment: @Ramhound - from the beginning of your 2nd comment... it's not just likely, it's an absolute. That's how a Mac 'knows' the lid is closed, magnetic proximity. That's also what holds the clamshell closed, rather than any kind of mechanical catch.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I realize after my first comment, what was going on, still say its not an intential design flaw that an external magnet is activating the sensor though.

Answer (score -1):

It's way more common than what you think. Many consumers electronics depends on this kind of sensors. The reason behind this is that you can conceal a small magnet away from the user and not use a mechanical, or piezoelectric, switch. Which will get stuck with dirt over time, asides from being plain ugly.